# Fourier Series Using the Odd and Even extensions

Tags: fourier-series, even-and-odd-functions

For the function $f(x)=x$ where x belongs to [0,$\pi$], I have found the Fourier series for $f_e(x)$ and $f_o(x)$.

If I wanted to find the Fourier Series of the function, can I add the series together, if not is there a shortcut method to calculate the Fourier series for $f(x)=x$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add the even and odd Fourier series. This is because breaking the series into real-valued even and odd series is a special case of the more general [complex Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Complex-valued_functions) where you treat $e^{ix}$ as separate cosine and sine terms with real coefficients.